# How do I display the framerate (fps) in SimCity on a Mac?

Tags: simcity-2013, framerate

I'm trying to find the best graphics settings for my Mac but can't compare because I can't see what the framerate is.  How do I display the framerate on SimCity?

Answer (score 1):

Bring up the console (press "~") and type `PerfOverlay.DrawFPS 1`. To remove the FPS counter, use the same command but replace the 1 with a 0.

Comment: Hi this doesn't work.  This is the latest SimCity that is on Origin.

Comment: Well what happens when you enter the command?

Comment: Nothing, '~' doesn't do anything.

Comment: OK, it may be a different key or key combination. Try "`" or CTRL+SHIFT+C